# MYSQL select dates before today

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL statement that expected to select all the days at least seven days before today

I used the code as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM letter WHERE letter.l_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

But did not get the desired result. I can not understand what I am going wrong. Can anyone help me Pls.?

Comment: Do yo mean all days before today except the last 7 days? Or in other words all dates older than 7 days ago?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you want it just from the last seven days including today, you need to specify that l_date is before now:

```
SELECT * FROM letter WHERE letter.l_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: I need all the dates, without the range of 7 days from today. (eg:- dates before  '2015-10-24'). In the other words excluding from the last seven days from today.

Comment: Do you need them after today as well?

Comment: before today. But excluding 7 days past from today

Comment: check my edit now, your greater than shouldve been a less than.

Answer (score 3):

if you need last 7 days data use `DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY`

```
SELECT * FROM letter WHERE letter.l_date > DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: I need all the dates, which are in 7 days ago from today

Comment: SELECT * FROM letter WHERE letter.l_date >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY

Comment: can you try this query ?

Comment: If you have data missing, then it wont be there? can we see your data?

Comment: Letter table included l_dates as: '2015-10-30', '2015-10-29', '2015-10-28', '2015-10-26', '2015-10-23' like that. But the above statement outputs '2015-10-29', '2015-10-28' too.

Answer (score 0):

Another way You can use [DATEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function

```
SELECT * FROM letter WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), letter.l_date) > 7
```